# Should I alter an Index to include a filter in Postgresql 9.6

Tags: postgresql, optimization, postgresql-performance, index-tuning

I have a query which I am looking to improve on with potentially a new index.

```
SELECT COUNT(price_id)
FROM price.price
WHERE (
          (
              (userid = '3081217')
              AND (
                      ('f' = 't')
                      OR (price_is_settled = 'f')
                  )
          )
          AND (
                  (
                      ('f' = 't')
                      OR (
                             (price_rejection_code_id IS NOT NULL)
                             AND ('f' = 't')
                         )
                  )
                  OR (
                         (price_rejection_code_id IS NULL)
                         AND ('f' <> 't')
                     )
              )
      );
```

At present there is an index covering the query on `(userid) WHERE price_rejection_code_id IS NULL` but looking at an explain of this, I can see there is a filter on `(NOT price_is_settled)`.

Would a general rule of thumb be to apply an index to include the filtered part also as the explain says?

The size of the price table is 72million rows.

Comment: I tried to format the query so different levels of conditions can be seen better. Is the code generated by sone kind of ORM? The `('f' = 't')` and `('f' = 't')` make it look even more complex than it is.

Comment: @jkavalik its generated by the app, just ran the query through an explain and noticed the additional filter on the not price_is_settled, curious as to whether its wise to just index on every column mentioned in the query.

Comment: Not blindly _"on every column"_, no, that would lead to many indexes, most of them not very useful. What a query often need though is a _composite index_ - your filtered indexes are sort-of-composite because the filtering covers additional information.

Comment: @jkavalik should I alter my index to include the additional column?

Comment: hard to say if you should :) but you could

Comment: For a proper answer, you'll have to provide information as instructed here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info - as well as more about frequency and importance of the query at hand (and queries that might use the same index)

Answer (score 1):

Why all the obfuscation? Your query boils down to:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM   price.price
WHERE  userid = '3081217'  -- why quotes? Isn't this a number?
AND    price_is_settled = false
AND    price_rejection_code_id IS NULL
```

Assuming `price_id` is defined `NOT NULL` (probably the PK), then `count(*)` is equivalent, a bit faster, and might allow index-only scans more easily.

**If** ...

- the query is used a lot and/or important
- the filter `NOT price_is_settled` is used all the time
- more than a few rows actually have `price_is_settled IS NOT FALSE`

... then it makes sense to ***replace*** the index you mentioned with this one:

```
CREATE INDEX ON price.price (userid)
WHERE price_rejection_code_id IS NULL AND price_is_settled = false;
```

**Else**, you need to disclose proper information. Index optimization depends on the complete picture.

Also, if performance matters, upgrade to a current version. [Postgres 9.6 reaches EOL as we speak (2011-11-11)](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/), and current versions have lots of improvements for big data.

Comment: Thansk @erwin-brandstetter with regards to the price_is_settled IS NOT False there are currently 59m that are true and 12m that are false. Would it be wise to have a separate indexes to cover both, the query itself is executed thousands of times throughout the day. The userid column is serial4 data type.

Comment: @rdbmsNoob: The added predicate on the partial index would greatly reduce the size of the index and should make the query at hand substantially faster. Can't say if it can replace the old index. That depends on what else is going on in the database. Only keep indexes that are actually useful, as they add write cost and occupy disk space and effect cache memory, too ...